# How to get from Put-O to Kyaing Tong

Tags: public-transport, myanmar

How can I go from Put-O to Kyaing Tong in the Shan state without returning to Yangon?

Comment: Are you talking about Keng Tung and Puta-o?

Answer (score 3):

I can suggest you way by air:

1. Move from Putao to Mandalay (flight K7625 Air KBZ) 45m + 1h 15m
2. Move from Mandalay to Keng Tung (flight W9425 Air Bagan) 1h 05m

Answer (score 0):

Mandalay is the best choice to connect from Putao to Kyaing Tong.